# node.js package.json scripts での mac と windows 共通のパス指定方法

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.js の npm package.json の書式について教えてください。

タイトルの通りなのですが
HTMLファイルを起動したいと思っています。
Windows と Mac とでパス記載が異なるために下記のようにコマンドを分ける必要があるように思いますが、これを統合する方法はありますか？

UNIX形式のパスを指定したらファイルを起動するような node用のjs ファイルを作ったらいいという事かもしれませんが、デフォルトで用意されていないものだろうかと思いました。

よろしくお願いします。

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test:win": ".\\test\\test.html",
    "test:mac": "./test/test.html",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己回答です。

cpx などと同じように opener というものがありました。こちらを使うとよいです。
同様なものにopn-cli などもありました。

opener - npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/opener